# Root finding occasionally fails. Can fSolve be given limits for 2D optimization?

Tags: python, optimization, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to find roots to a 2D optimization problem, of the form (below is not the actual equation as it's very long, this is just an example of the style of problem).

```
def my_function(a,b):
    c = exp(a) + b
    d = a + 2 - exp(b)
    return c, d
```

I want to know a and b, for which c and d are zero.

So far, I'm using fsolve from the scipy optimize library, and passing the seed values as values which I know are close to the solution. This works well, although on some occasional, fails and I get the error about the solver "not making good progress over last 10 iterations".

I wonder if there's a way / general good practice for making root finding more robust?

Otherwise, I'd like to try bounded-root-finding. In 1D, fminbound can be used, but I can't find a function that will let me specify bounds for a 2D problem.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Should we assume that in your "actual" problem, it isn't possible to solve for `b` in terms of `a`?  The best approach is to exploit relationships among free variables to analytically reduce the problem to 1D.

Answer (score 1):

In the big picture, there is no general way to make root finding more robust - there is a reason there are so many different functions in scipy.optimize!

One trick is rather than finding roots of f(x) you can instead try to find minimas of f^2(x).  Finding minimas is often more robust because the algorithm just needs to keep going downhill to the bottom.  However, the downside is that the minima found might not be at f(x)=0 (i.e. not a root).

So, you could try scipy.optimize.fmin_tnc which is a minimizer with bounds and see what happens.

Good guesses are always helpful, but 'close' might not always be best - you might look more deeply at the function and figure out what the landscape 'close' by really looks like, and if 'close' (or far!) in a different direction might be easier for the solver (that is, one direction might be quite choppy requiring going over mountains to find the valley, while another direction has a beautiful broad path down to the bottom of the valley).